# Can't use HybridCache of Cache library for Swift

Tags: swift, caching

I used HybridCache of Cache Library for Swift for my app.
I updated Cache Library 2.2.2 to 5.2.0. 
And then I got an Error.
This is error message for HybridCache

```
 Use of unresolved identifier 'HybridCache'
```

This is code

```
fileprivate let cache = HybridCache(name: "ReadGirl.JSONCache")
```

I found the article for HybridCache.
https://github.com/hyperoslo/Cache/issues/150

And I changed the code to this.

```
    let diskConfig = DiskConfig(name: "ReadGirl.JSONCache")
    let memoryConfig = MemoryConfig(expiry: .never, countLimit: 10, totalCostLimit: 10)
    fileprivate let cache = try? Storage(
        diskConfig: diskConfig,  // Error
        memoryConfig: memoryConfig
    )
```

But I got another error message to "diskConfig".
This is message.

```
Cannot use instance member 'diskConfig' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

Do I have to use some function to Storage?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in other instance variables, `diskConfig` and `memoryConfig` to the initializer of `cache`, but since all properties are initialized at the same time, this is not possible. You can however, mark `cache` as `lazy`, which means that it will only be evaluated the first time it is accessed. First access can only happen after the enclosing instance was already initialized, so it is safe to use another instance variable from the initializer of a `lazy` property.

```
let diskConfig = DiskConfig(name: "ReadGirl.JSONCache")
let memoryConfig = MemoryConfig(expiry: .never, countLimit: 10, totalCostLimit: 10)
fileprivate lazy var cache = try? Storage(
    diskConfig: diskConfig,
    memoryConfig: memoryConfig,
    transformer: TransformerFactory.forData()
)
```

Another possible solution if you don't need to access `diskConfig` or `memoryConfig` from outside your `cache` variable would be to directly pass them into the initializer instead of storing it as an instance variable.

```
fileprivate let cache = try? Storage(
    diskConfig: DiskConfig(name: "ReadGirl.JSONCache"),
    memoryConfig: MemoryConfig(expiry: .never, countLimit: 10, totalCostLimit: 10),
    transformer: TransformerFactory.forData()
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I tried `Lazy` and into the initializer.  I think, it's make sense.  But, I got other error.

First I tried `Lazy`. It make this message, "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Storage<_>' with an argument list of type '(diskConfig: DiskConfig, memoryConfig: MemoryConfig)"
And into initializer make this message, "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" DiskConfig is struct.  Does struct have some type?

Comment: @NoriyasuKatano check my updated answer, the `Storage` initializer seems to have been updated since that GitHub issue was created. You might need to modify the `transformer` input parameter's value depending on what you want to cache

Comment: @NoriyasuKatano glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please mark it as the accepted answer using the tick symbol next to the answer.